# Performing a function on dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am trying to winsorize a data set that would contain a few hundred columns of data. I'd like to make a new column to the dataframe and the column would contain the winsorized result from its row's data. How can I do this with a pandas dataframe without having to specify each column (I'd like to use all columns)?

Edit: I would want to use the function 'winsorize(list, limits = [0.1,0.1])' but I'm not sure how to format the dataframe rows to work as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- You may use the pandas function `apply` with `axis=1` to apply a function to every row.
- The apply function will receive a pandas `Series` object but you can easily convert it to a list using `tolist` method

For example:

```
df.apply(lambda x: winsorize(x.tolist(), limits=[0.1,0.1]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numpy version of your dataframe using `to_numpy()`

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize

ma = winsorize(df.to_numpy(), axis=1, limits=[0.1, 0.1])
out = pd.DataFrame(ma.data, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?